# Shared code between Kotlin server and client projects using Gradle

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I want to share some of the code between the server (JVM) and the client (JS) using a separate `shared` project. I've seen a [solution](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.html) using Maven, but I'm not sure how to convert this to a Gradle project. Also, there aren't any examples of shared projects in the [official guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html). So, how would a minimal `build.gradle` with such setup look?

Comment: Note that this is a pretty old question and while the answers might still apply, today you should look into [Kotlin multiplatform projects](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multiplatform.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building a Kotlin2JS project with dependencies from another Kotlin projects seems to require copying the sources in any way. One way to do it is adding the Kotlin project source dirs to the Kotlin2JS project source set dirs.

This can be done with the following lines in `project` scope:

```
sourceSets {  
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += project(':shared').sourceSets.main.kotlin.srcDirs
}
```

Please see the whole project structure:

```
root/
  shared/
    src/main/kotlin
    build.gradle
  client/
    src/main/kotlin
  server/
    src/main/kotlin
  build.gradle
  settings.gradle
```

In `settings.gradle`:

```
include 'shared', 'server', 'client'
```

And in `build.gradle`:

```
group 'com.example.multiproject'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-beta-4589"
    }
}

subprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

project(':client') {
    evaluationDependsOn(':shared')

    apply plugin: 'kotlin2js'
    compileKotlin2Js.kotlinOptions.sourceMap = true
    compileKotlin2Js.kotlinOptions.outputFile = "${projectDir}/web/js/app.js"
    compileKotlin2Js.kotlinOptions.suppressWarnings = true
    compileKotlin2Js.kotlinOptions.verbose = true

    sourceSets {
        main.kotlin.srcDirs += project(':shared').sourceSets.main.kotlin.srcDirs
    }
    dependencies {
        compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-js-library:1.0.0-beta-4589'
    }
}

project(':server') {
    apply plugin: 'kotlin'
    dependencies {
        compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.0-beta-4589'
        compile project(':shared')
    }
}
```

Note that `shared` project should contain its own `build.gradle`.

Comment: Have you tried using this setup? I already knew how to create multi-project setups, but the thing is - it seems that both server and client depend on different plugins and libraries. If I'm correct, Kotlin client project should use `kotlin2js` plugin and `kotlin-js-library` instead of `kotlin` plugin and `kotlin-stdlib`. I'm currently trying the multi-project approach, but: A) when using `idea` plugin, IntelliJ doesn't see source folders, so there's a lot of manual setup, B) if importing as Gradle project, external dependencies are not linked. I'll upload my scripts when I'm completely stuck.

Comment: @JustACluelessNewbie, I agree, I missed the JS moment. Could you please provide me a kotlin2js plugin dependency for buildscript? I think that it will be similar to what I wrote, just using different plugins for different projects instead of one in `subprojects`.

Comment: @JustACluelessNewbie, I've updated the answer. This buildscript gets configured on my side and seems to be correct, but I don't know how to check if `client` builds correctly. Please check the current version in your project. However, both `client` and `server` are able to use classes from `shared`.

Comment: JS plugin is not enough if you want the client to actually see shared sources, that's what I've initially started with. `gradle client:build` fails to compile client code using classes from shared project. Also, `kotlin-stdlib` is JVM-only, I think. I was struggling with a task that appends shared source dirs before JS compilation, but I think the solution can be much simpler. I asked the question to see if anyone already has got a working solution - I'm not a total Gradle beginner.

Comment: @JustACluelessNewbie, OK, I tried and got the same, so removing the answer for now.

Comment: @JustACluelessNewbie, I was able to build the `client` project, please see the updated answer.

Comment: I recently managed to build the client project with `main.kotlin.srcDirs += '../shared/src/main/kotlin'`, but your solution seems more elegant. I'll test it later and accept the answer.

Comment: This works for me when I compile from the command line in Gradle. It also works in IntelliJ IDEA for the client project. However the server project can't see any of the shared code and wants me to add a dependency on the client project to resolve this :(

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, this is the setup I was creating pretty much simultaneously with **hotkey**:

Main `settings.gradle`: `include 'shared', 'client', 'server'`

Main `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
  ext {
    kotlinVer = '1.0.0-beta-4589'
  }
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
      url 'http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVer"
  }
}

allprojects {
  apply plugin: 'idea'
  group = 'some.company'
  version = '0.0.1'

  ext {
    kotlinVer = '1.0.0-beta-4589'
    // Lib versions go there.
  }
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
  }
}

project('shared') {
  apply plugin: 'kotlin'
}

project('server') {
  apply plugin: 'kotlin'
  apply plugin: 'application'

  mainClassName = 'some.company.Main'
  dependencies {
    compile project(':shared')
  }
}

project('client') {
  apply plugin: 'kotlin2js'
  dependencies {
    compile project(':shared')
  }
}
```

Client `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin2js'

compileKotlin2Js {
  kotlinOptions.outputFile = "server/src/main/resources/static/js/app.js"
  kotlinOptions.sourceMap = true
}

sourceSets {
  main.kotlin.srcDirs += '../shared/src/main/kotlin'
  // hotkey's solution:
  // main.kotlin.srcDirs += project(':shared').sourceSets.main.kotlin.srcDirs
}

dependencies {
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-js-library:$kotlinVer"
}
```

Server `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

dependencies {
  // Libs go there.
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlinVer"
  testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlinVer"
}
```

Shared project's `build.gradle` contains only `apply plugin: 'kotlin'` and, well, I'm not sure if using shared libraries is straightforward (or necessary, in many cases), so I guess it could even stay empty.

`gradle client:build` generates JavaScript file in server's static resources folder. `gradle idea` generates IntelliJ project with correctly linked dependencies and source folders (as long as the default names are used - `src/main/kotlin`, etc; see official Kotlin Gradle manual for custom source dirs).